# Multi Site Manager gives 404 when using Sub Folder

Tags: multi-site-manager, 404

We have setup Multisite Manager but we are not using sub-domains, we want them in sub-folders. The EE instructions do not reference this setup, only domains and sub-domains. Its not working for us, accessing a page on the site causes the default site 404 to kick in. We are using the Pages module, so segment_1 would refer to the site_url.

We have configured all the necessary settings in the instructions.

We have also added into Site 2's .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

Note: Site 2's home page works fine. Its just pages. Template Groups are not called either (for example /news) so I don't think its a Pages issue.

Further, it seems Pages, being a module, is not copied when duplicating a site. Pages is empty, no templates are assigned. Although an old post, it is referenced here:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/177005/#839555

Looks like I have to manually set it all up again, and edit each page. I did this but it still does not work.

I do not have a Template Group named as my sub-folder.

Anyone know any extra configuration steps for sub folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ha ha, found it!

Removing index.php code in the .htaccess file also needed updating.

Original RewriteRule to remove index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

New RewriteRule needs the sub-folder added to the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Note**: the question mark after index.php depends on a server setting, so dont copy and paste, but check first what yours is.